# MVC 4 Accessing the Parent Model object in the Child Post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC 4 framework, I have a Parent and Child View (put Child in Html.Partial). I used Jquery dialog in showing the Child View.  In my Child View, I have a Submit button. I want the data that I inputted in the Parent View to be retained upon posting back the Child View. Is it possible to access the Model object of the Parent View, so that I can still pass the Parent Model Object in the HttpPost  method of the Child View?

Here's my sample code for **ParentView**:

```
@model Model.PurchaseOrderModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>Parent</div>

    <div id="ItemDialog"  style="display: none;">
         @Html.Partial("ChildView")
     </div>
}
```

Here's my sample code for **ChildView**:

```
<div>

   <div>Child</div>

   <div>
      <input type="submit" id="btnSaveItems" text="Save" value="Save Items" />
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you use `JQuery ajax` to `post` only child data to server, in that case there will not be a page refresh and no need to post parent model as well.

Comment: @ramiramilu The reason why I need to pass the Parent Model object is because after the user click the Child View Submit button, the dialog will be automatically closed and will go back to the Parent View. Please see my sample code above.

Comment: Yes I understand, but my point is instead of using traditional submit post, why can't you use jQuery AJAX post on your child view. In that case page will not be refreshed and your parent modal will be persisted on form.

Comment: So change the button type from submit to button, then handle the click event in jquery in which you make a ajax call to server with child view data, on success function of the ajax call, close the popup.

Comment: @ramiramilu But if I'll do your suggestion, is it still possible to update the Model of the Parent View upon returning on it? Because the items that I have added in the Child view should reflect on the Parent View upon closing the popup dialog.

Comment: Yes, you can update the parent view, as a simple option, probably just refresh the page using `window.location.href = 'same page url'`. Or else you can return the newly created or updated items in the `AJAX success` call and use that data in jquery to update the parent view.

Comment: @ramiramilu I preferred your second suggestion wherein I have to use AJAX call. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.